# Action Mode modify the action menu dynamically

Tags: android, listview

I extend [`AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener.html) for multi selection in `ListView`, I want to change the action menu dynamically (when more than one `ListView` item selected).

```
private class ModeCallback implements ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {
        //inflate menu 
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.compose_multi_select_menu, menu);
        }
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            //want to remove some menu here, but not work
            if (getListView().getCheckedItemCount() > 1) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(5);
            menu.removeItem();
            }
        }

}
```

I try to remove `MenuItem` in `onPrepareActionMode()`, but not work. Also tried  `mode.invalidate()` in `onItemCheckedStateChanged()`.

Actually, I find in `onPrepareActionMode()` the `menu` passed in have no `MenuItem` at all.

Anyone can help on this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can modify menu in your onItemCheckedStateChanged() by showing or hiding items like this:

```
Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
menu.findItem(R.id.some_item_id).setVisible(false);
```

where `mode` is `ActionMode` passed to `onItemCheckedStateChanged`